# Using upper() and lower() functions with tstzrange type in JPQL in Hibernate 6 with Quarkus 3

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, quarkus, hibernate-types

I'm developing a Quarkus 3 application where I've integrated Hibernate 6. To work with custom PostgreSQL types, specifically `tstzrange`, I've incorporated `hypersistence-utils-hibernate-62` from hypersistence-utils. This serves as a replacement for the older hibernate-types.

However looks like now I can not use upper() and lower() functions anymore in JPQ, for example:

```
List<Restriction> resultList = entityManager.createQuery(
    "from AgeRestriction where upper(rangeZonedDateTime) is not null", 
    Restriction.class
).getResultList();
```

Here, `rangeZonedDateTime` is defined as a `tstzrange` type. When executing this, I encounter the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: Parameter 1 of function upper() has type STRING,
but argument is of type io.hypersistence.utils.hibernate.type.range.Range
```

It seems like Hibernate now interprets the `upper()` function as a string manipulation function (to convert characters to uppercase), rather than a function to get the upper bound of the tstzrange.

I've tried setting up a custom dialects in the application's configuration, but it doesn't seem to make any difference,, for example:

```
quarkus.hibernate-orm.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

Basically, I just extended this test:
https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hypersistence-utils/blob/master/hypersistence-utils-hibernate-62/src/test/java/io/hypersistence/utils/hibernate/type/range/ZonedDateTimeMilliSecondTest.java

Is it still possible to use upper/lower for range types in JPQL in Hibernate 6.x ?

Comment: Cast the input explicit to a tstzrange: upper (CAST(rangeZonedDateTime AS tstzrange))

Comment: @FrankHeikens but this could work only for native queries right? Here I have JPQL